# SQL working days function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

Im trying to work out the previous 5 working days, if its a Saturday or sunday then it needs to use Friday as the last working day.

Ive got the if else part of this query working but when I try to use this to create a function im getting error messages, any ideas what ive missed?

```
create table holidays  (
  date date);
GO



create function dbo.WorkDays
(

@date datetime, 
@days int

)

returns date 

as

Begin

IF datename(dw,@date) = 'Saturday' 

select dateadd(dd,-1,thedate)
  from (
  select thedate=dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)),
         rn=row_number() over (order by v.day),
         weekday = datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)))
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))v(day)
  left join holidays h on h.date = dateadd(d,v.day,cast(@date as date))
  where left(datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date))),1) <> 'S'
  ) x
  where @days = rn

Else If datename(dw,@date) = 'Sunday'

select dateadd(dd,-1,thedate)
  from (
  select thedate=dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)),
         rn=row_number() over (order by v.day),
         weekday = datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)))
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))v(day)
  left join holidays h on h.date = dateadd(d,v.day,cast(@date as date))
  where left(datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date))),1) <> 'S'
  ) x
  where @days = rn

Else

select thedate
  from (
  select thedate=dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)),
         rn=row_number() over (order by v.day),
         weekday = datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)))
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))v(day)
  left join holidays h on h.date = dateadd(d,v.day,cast(@date as date))
  where left(datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date))),1) <> 'S'
  ) x
  where @days = rn

End 

drop table holidays
```

Comment: Care to tell us what the error messages are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error showed is:
*Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.*

You need to declare a @return variable, and assign it the output of each select statement:

```
create function dbo.WorkDays
(

@date datetime, 
@days int

)

returns date 

as

Begin
DECLARE @return date

IF datename(dw,@date) = 'Saturday' 

select @return = dateadd(dd,-1,thedate)
  from (
  select thedate=dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)),
         rn=row_number() over (order by v.day),
         weekday = datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)))
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))v(day)
  left join holidays h on h.date = dateadd(d,v.day,cast(@date as date))
  where left(datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date))),1) <> 'S'
  ) x
  where @days = rn

Else If datename(dw,@date) = 'Sunday'

select @return = dateadd(dd,-1,thedate)
  from (
  select thedate=dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)),
         rn=row_number() over (order by v.day),
         weekday = datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)))
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))v(day)
  left join holidays h on h.date = dateadd(d,v.day,cast(@date as date))
  where left(datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date))),1) <> 'S'
  ) x
  where @days = rn

Else

select @return= thedate
  from (
  select thedate=dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)),
         rn=row_number() over (order by v.day),
         weekday = datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date)))
  from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))v(day)
  left join holidays h on h.date = dateadd(d,v.day,cast(@date as date))
  where left(datename(dw,dateadd(d,-v.day,cast(@date as date))),1) <> 'S'
  ) x
  where @days = rn


  return @return
End
```

I suppose the logic of your queries is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [DBName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetWorkdays]
(
@f datetime=null,@t datetime=null

)
RETURNS int 
AS

BEGIN
 declare @retVal int=0

  set @retVal=( 
                  select count(DyName) as DayCnt
                    from  CalenderInfo where 
                    DteName between @f and @t  and DyName not in('Friday')
                    and DteName not in  
                    ( select Fromdate from  HolidayInfo where Fromdate between @f and @t  )

   )

 return @retVal


END
```

Table 1: Calenderinfo

```
DayID   int
DyName  varchar(20)
DteName datetime
```

Table 2: HolidayInfo

```
HolidayDetailsID    int
HolidayID   int
HolydayName varchar(100)
Fromdate    datetime
Todate  datetime
IsPublic    int
IsCalculated    int
IsInactive  int
```